# No GRUB menu during Ubuntu boot with 2 displays

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04, dual booting alongside Windows, but nothing shows up on both monitors on boot up w/ Ubuntu. I know that it is taking place in the background because it automatically selects the primary option from the BIOS (in this case Ubuntu). My PC runs an [KFA2 GeForce GTX 1060 6GB OC](https://www.kfa2.com/kfa2/graphics-card/kfa2-geforce-gtx-1060-oc-6gb.html) into these monitors:

[Acer Nitro VG240Y](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.QV0AA.P01) connected via DisplayPort

[ASUS VG248QE](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VG248QE/) connected via HDMI cable

If I take the power cable out of the Acer Nitro display, the boot up shows up fine on my ASUS monitor and I pick which to boot into with the [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) menu, but nothing shows up when both monitors are connected to the PC.

This issue also persisted when loading up Windows but it was never a problem because I never had to dual boot two operating systems previously. But now I have to keep disconnecting the power cable from my monitor in order to select between Ubuntu and Windows. I can not enter the BIOS menu either on start up with both monitors, only when the Acer monitor is disconnected. 
How can I troubleshoot this? lshw data follows.

```
product: 7200-5341A (7200-5341A)
           *-display
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: 1) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 2) KFA2 GeForce GTX 1060 6GB OC Graphics Card, GDDR5, 3) Added to question